# Open specific page using input data in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open http://10.41.30.88/mmisweb/plpodtl.asp?pl=30010111 in another tab, where user has to input the last eight digits. (Which is 30010111 in this case for example).

For input I have to use HTML page and JavaScript. I used the following -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="http://10.41.30.88/mmisweb/plpodtl.asp?pl=" id="baseUrl">Link Text</a>
<input type="text" id="appendUrl" onclick="ass();return false; "/>
<script>
function ass() {

        window.location = $(this).attr('href')  + $('#appendUrl').val();
        return false;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it returns only http://10.41.30.88/mmisweb/plpodtl.asp?pl= in the window and not the digits.

Comment: This change also didn't help. Still the digits are not returned.

Answer (score 1):

Onclick must be in the link....

```
 <a href="http://10.41.30.88/mmisweb/plpodtl.asp?pl=" id="baseUrl" onclick="ass();">
```

You have return false too, is no neccesary in onclick.

Comment: The original problem remains. The digits are not returned.

Comment: It's because your code is very bad structurate. See this fiddle and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ef9jnrvz   Only you must to change your thinking and all is ok